# phantom cucumber step

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

Running guard with cucumber and rspec. While getting some recent tests to pass, the following started showing up in every cucumber run:

```
Running all features
Disabling profiles...
Running tests with args ["--no-profile", "--color", "--format", "progress", "--strict", "--require", "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-cucumber-1.1.0/lib/guard/cucumber/notification_formatter.rb", "--format", "Guard::Cucumber::NotificationFormatter", "--out", "/dev/null", "--require", "features", "features"]...
Disabling profiles...
....................................U-----........................

10 scenarios (1 undefined, 9 passed)
63 steps (5 skipped, 1 undefined, 57 passed)
0m3.703s

You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

Given /^I fill in "(.*?)""$/ do |arg1|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

Done.
```

I cannot find `Given /^I fill in "(.*?)""$/` in any `.feature` files!  I've grepped the entire application directory structure and it's just not there (`grep -Hr "I fill in" *`).

Now, just to be clear, there is a `When /^I fill in "(.*?)" with "(.*?)"$/ do |title, text|` step that I use frequently, but that is not what cucumber is talking about in the above code snippet.

Bueller?

Thanks!

Comment: You have a sort of indication there: the **U** for undefined is the 37th step ;-). But the total steps number doesn't seem to be coherent with the total number of dots.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. In one of our `.feature` files, there was a closing quote missing, so it messed up the parsing of the following step. Tracked it down by manually running each of our feature files one at a time with `be cucumber feature/filename.feature`